# How to use child class when applying dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

here is the interface

```
public interface IBaseWorker
{
    Task<WorkResult> IntializeWork();
    Task<WorkResult> DoWork();
    Task<WorkResult> SendEmail();
}
```

Here is my base class.

```
public abstract class BaseWorker : IBaseWorker
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    protected readonly IDatabaseCommonService _databaseCommonService;
    protected List<ClientConfigurations> clientConfigurations;  

    public BaseWorker(ILogger logger, IDatabaseCommonService databaseCommonService)
    {
        _databaseCommonService = databaseCommonService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public virtual async Task<WorkResult> IntializeWork()
    {
        Do something... 
    }

    public abstract Task<WorkResult> DoWork();

    public abstract Task<WorkResult> SendEmail();
}
```

here is my child class.

```
 public class ChildWorker : BaseWorker 
{
    public ChildWorker(
        ILogger<ChildWorker> logger, 
        IDatabaseCommonService databaseCommonService) : base(logger, databaseCommonService)
    {

    }

    public override Task<WorkResult> DoWork()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override Task<WorkResult> SendEmail()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

now I want to use this child class in another class. please tell me the best way to do it. I didn't create a interface to this child class. I want to use dependency injection. is this ok to use without the interface.

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass 
{
   private readonly ChildWorker _childWorker;
  
   public MyClass(ChildWorker childWorker){
      _childWorker = childWorker
   }  

   public void method(){
      _childWorker.IntializeWork();
   } 
}
```

if this is not ok could someone please tell me a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply injecting a concrete class is supported.  If your class doesn't cause problems for testing purposes, or the caller simply doesn't need to be tested for whatever reason, nothing stops you from doing this.